# How can I add redux form into my dispatch function?

Tags: javascript, forms, reactjs, redux, redux-form

Currently I am trying to dispatch some actions in react/redux and I am also using redux form. How do I go about implementing redux form within the react-redux connect function?

Dispatch Function:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return{
    authUser: () => {
      dispatch(authUser());
    },
    signIn: () => {
      dispatch(authUser());
    }
  }
}
```

Then using the react-redux connect function:

```
export default reduxForm({
  validate, form: 'signInForm'})
(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps) (SignIn))
```

When passing in the signIn function to the mapDispatchToProps, the form then stops submitting?

mapStateToProps function:

```
function mapStateToProps(state){
  return {
    SignInDetails: state.SignInDetails,
    isAuthenticated: state.isAuthenticated
  }
}
```

signIn Reducer:

```
import _ from 'lodash';
const SIGN_IN_FULFILLED = 'SIGN_IN_FULFILLED';

export default function(state, action){
  //eslint-disable-next-line
  switch (action.type) {
    case SIGN_IN_FULFILLED:
      return _.mapKeys(action.payload.data, 'id');
    default:
      return {};
  }
}
```

Comment: can i see mapStateToProps and the reducer file

Comment: @Aaqib ive added it to the question

Comment: MapStateToProps?

Comment: @Aaqib I've updated that now sorry

Comment: whats the components name you are binding connect with ? And can i see actions

Comment: @Aaqib the component is called SignIn

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux' ;
import { reduxForm } from 'redux-form';

...




export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(reduxForm({
      form: 'signInForm',
      validate
})(SignIn));
```